# How to stick div to bottom page no scrolling

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have the following html struct:

```
<body>
<div class="content">
   ...here long content
</div>
<div class="footer">
    ...here some rows for footer
</div>
</body>
```

i want to strick the footer part to bottom page and the content page need to be in all the other place in page with scroll only in his part. **!important!** not scrolling in all page - only in content part.

something like this:

[image]

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: You need mainly 3 css styles: `position: absolute; height: some px; bottom: 0;`. You can get more easy help, if you create a [FIDDLE](jsfiddle.net)

Comment: @Abhi i would say position;fixed and not absolute

Comment: Yes, it is possible, https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fixed_footer.asp

Comment: It is Possible , Do you Want to Fix the Position of Footer ?? Or you want the footer to the end of the page after content . If you will Fix the Position than on scroll the footer will be on the same position .

Comment: @TemaniAfif My bad. You'r right !!!

Comment: Hi, i want to fix it in bottom even if content is empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply do this :

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.content {
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  overflow: auto;
  background: red;
  padding: 50px;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem
  ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum
  lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem
  ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem
  ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
  ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem
  ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
  lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</div>
<div class="footer">
  ...here some rows for footer
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Make your content div into a scroll-able div so you can keep the footer at the bottom anytime

```
<div class="content" style="overflow:scroll; height:400px;">
```

If you want only vertical scrolling try this

```
<div class="content" style="overflow-y: scroll; height:400px;">
```